# Malaysian Transit Visa for Indian working in Japan

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia

I am holding an Indian passport. Currently working in Japan. During my vacation to India, I wanted to visit Kuala Lumpur. So I booked Tokyo to Kuala Lumpur with AirAsiaX airlines and 3 days later, I have a next flight with Indigo airlines from Kuala Lumpur to India. I booked both the tickets differently. Am I eligible to get Transit Visa for those 3 days?